# Can we remove an element from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I create a lot of react component dynamically on event handle.
The code is given blow:

```js
var node = []; //this is update with properties on user action and an element is creaed 
var node = Interfaces.Embroidery.node;
var components = node.map(function(props) {
  return React.createElement('g', {
      id: props.id,
      key: props.id
    },
    React.createElement('path', props));
});

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.createElement('div', null, components);
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App), document.getElementById('parentDrawingNode'));
```

now i want to remove a single element from the dom. i.e it will be a user action component or i want to remove in some special case  and other component remain same.

By use refs of we are dealing with actual dom so the refs are not applicable in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the point of React.  You don't manually modify the element tree.  You declaratively map properties/state to elements and let React do all of the modifications.

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    // Get the node from the passed-in props
    var node = this.props.node;

    // generate the child components
    var components = node.map(function(props) {
      return React.createElement('g', {
        id: props.id,
        key: props.id
      },
      React.createElement('path', props));
    });

    // render them in a div
    return React.createElement('div', null, components);
  }
});


// first time it will create the DOM
// after that it just modifies the DOM
function renderApp(node, element) {
  ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, { node: node }), element);
}

// Call when you want to get rid of the App completely
// and cleanup memory without reloading the page
function destroyApp(element) {
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(element);
}

// Initial render
var node = Interfaces.Embroidery.node;
renderApp(node, document.getElementById('parentDrawingNode'));

function updateNodeOnSomeUserActionThatHappensOutsideOfReact(...) {
  node.push(...); // or whatever modification you want

  // re-render
  renderApp(node, document.getElementById('parentDrawingNode'));
}
```

Read more about this style here: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/01/react-render-and-top-level-api.html

Note this is what you'd do if the "user actions" are occurring outside of your React components (i.e. elsewhere in the app).  If the "user actions" occur as events within your React components, you'd only ever call `render` once, and instead the App would hold the nodes as `state` and would just call `this.setState({ node: modifiedNodes });` to change the state, which would cause React to update your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating react elements using the array `node`, you can base your succeeding actions in adding or removing elements on it.

push, slice, concat etc...

i.e. `node.push( {id: id, key: key })` to add elements

`node.splice()` to remove elements